# How do I reset an increment identity's starting value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, identity

I would like to have a nice template for doing this in development. How do I reset an increment identity's starting value in SQL Server?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('TableName', RESEED, 0)
```

Answer (score 36):

Just a word of warning with:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (MyTable, RESEED, 0)
```

If you did not truncate the table, and the identity column is the PK, you will get an error when reaching pre-existing identites.

For example, you have identities (3,4,5) in the table already.  You then reset the identity column to 1.  After the identity 2 is inserted, the next insert will try to use the identity 3, which will fail.

Comment: I don't know what truncating here is referring to, but if in doubt issue `select max(customerid) from customers` to see what the highest existing value is

Answer (score 17):

To set the identity to 100:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (MyTable, RESEED, 100)
```

Comment: This will mean the next identity is 101 by the way - and so "0" to reset the next inserted to "1".

Comment: @Kieren Johnstone - yes it will continue the numbering from 100, as if record 100 has just been added and so the next is 101.