# Changing the starting value of "int identity"

Tags: sql-server

I have been searching for how to change (alter) the starting value of the int identity in MSSQL Server. Currently it starts at 1, I need it to start at 1000?

Comment: What part of the BooksOnline description of the identity property didn't you understand?  This is clearly explained in the SQL Server help files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the Identity seed to that value:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable
(
 id int IDENTITY(9586,1)
)
```

To alter a current table:

```
ALTER TABLE orders ALTER COLUMN Id IDENTITY (9586, 1);
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but didn't worked (SQLServer over Linux).
The one that worked for me, it's that one from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16983/3122531)